# Tensorflow can find right cudnn in one python file but fail in another

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to use tensorflow gpu version to train and test my deep learning model. But here comes the problem. When I train my model in one python file things go on well. Tensorflow-gpu can be used properly. Then I save my model as a pretrained on as `grapg.pb` format and try to reuse it in another python file.

Then I got the following error messages.

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:363] Loaded runtime CuDNN 
library: 7.1.4 but source was compiled with: 7.2.1.  CuDNN library major 
and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of 
CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN 
library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime 
is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
```

I checked my cudnn version, in fact it is version `7.4.2`. I also checked my environment path settings `/cuda/v9.0/bin`, `cuda/v9.0/lib/x64`, `/cuda/v9.0/include` are in there.

So why this happens? And how can I solve this?

--

> cuda:`v9.0`
>   cudnn:`7.4.2` (I think, I copy those cudnn files manually)
>   windows 10
>   python: `3.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `CuDNN` installed thorough various ways like anaconda module and windows installation, you need to remove the older version in order for your code to detect the latest version and reinstall `tensorflow-gpu`.
You can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) guide for installation based on OS.